# Javascript to native Android calls do not work on Android 4.2

Tags: javascript, android

I have an Android app in which I am loading a static HTML page. Once the page is loaded I want to inject some javascript that will call a method from my Javascript Interface.

The problem is that this call is not done (I get an error: "Object has no method ...") when running on a device with Android 4.2.2.

**I know that in order for this to work for apps build for API level 17 or higher the method must be annotated with @JavascriptInterface. In that case it works. The problem that I have is because the app is built for API Level 10, I do not have access to @JavascriptInterface.**

At this point all I can think of is that if the app is build for an API Level smaller than 17. this will not work on devices running Android 4.2.2.

Do you have any ideas if this is true or not?

Comment: When you tried it on the emulator, what happened?

Comment: Only tried on device running 4.2 and 2.3.3. Works on 2.3.3, but not on 4.2

Comment: You might try building for API 17, but setting the minimum version lower. Something like <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>. I'm not certain if that would work or not (which is why this is a comment, rather than an answer).

Comment: @mah Building for minSdkVersion 1- will not give me access to JavascriptInterface annotation. This is not going to work. But thanks for trying :)

Comment: @mah You were right about this. Post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try building for API 17, but setting the minimum version lower. Something like <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

Answer (score 3):

> The problem that I have is because the app is built for API Level 10, I do not have access to @JavascriptInterface.

Change your build target to API Level 17 (e.g., in Eclipse, go to Project > Properties > Android). Set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 10, and Lint will point out to you places where you use things that exist on API Level 17 but do not exist on API Level 10.

At this point, you will be able to use `@JavascriptInterface`. You may also need to add a suitable `@TargetApi` annotation as well, based upon Lint complaints.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. After I posted the comment I realized that it should work as stated by @mah. I am sorry but I will ask him to post that as an answer and I will accept his. No hard feelings.

Comment: For what it's worth, @CommonsWare was my first Android teacher, at a seminar deep in the woods of Georgia. Sounds scary when put like that, but I assure you there was no deliverance, just a good Android foundation.